# Share whatsapp button for individual images

Tags: javascript, blogger, sharethis, share-button

i am making a webiste and a blog which is not yet launched but before I go live, I need to add a feature. I want to add whatsapp share button. I have searched for it and have used it on my site and blog and it works but the issue is that it shares link of the entire page and thumbnail. My question is, if I have 4 images on a page, and if I want to put a whatsapp share button underneath every all 4 images so that when it is clicked, the full image and a link with the image url will be shared on whatsapp. Is it even possible? I searched for it a lot but could not find anything. Would appreciate some help here.